# How to prevent this race condition?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, race-condition

We have a **Client** class which extends a **BaseClass**.

The **BaseClass** has this methods:

```
    protected void Proxy()
    {
        Error = null;
        _proxy = new WebServiceClient<T>(_fullURL);
        Error = _proxy.Error;
    }

    protected virtual void Cleanup()
    {
        if (_proxy != null)
        {
            _proxy.Dispose();
            _proxy = null;
        }
    }
```

And the **Client**  contains several operations that are being called in parallel. **Client** is not a Singleton, we generate one instance every time.

The operations are like:

```
public void OperationAsync(Action<BaseResult> callback)
{

    TaskCompletionSource<String> taskSrc = new TaskCompletionSource<String>();
    Task<String> tsk = taskSrc.Task;
    try
    {
        Proxy();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(t =>
        {
            try
            {
                String result = _proxy.Channel.ExecuteOperation(SecurityToken());
                taskSrc.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                taskSrc.SetException(ex);
            }
        });

        tsk.Wait();

        BaseResult r = new BaseResult();
        r.Value = tsk.Result;
        r.Error = tsk.Exception;
        Cleanup();

        if (callback != null)
        {
            callback(r);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        FileManager.Log(ex);
    }
}
```

As you can see, each operation calls the **Proxy** and **CleanUp** operations.

We did not discover any pattern of behavior yet, but sometimes (maybe once a day) we see this error in the log file:

*One or more errors occurred.. InnerException: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel'.*

It doesn´t happen on any specific operation. It varies all times.
I believe that the Proxy needs to be done during the constructor and the CleanUp during the dispose, but it implies to change several things and I want to be sure.

I would really appreciate any idea on how can improve it.

Comment: Why is `_proxy` a field at all? Why not make `Proxy` return a `WebServiceClient<T>` save it in a variable local to the function then pass in that variable to `Cleanup` Also, your background worker does nothing other than add additional overhead to your function call. If you are going to put work on another thread then immedatly call `.Wait()` for that thread to finish then you will always get worse performance in not using a extra thread at all.

Comment: You really need to stop writing `catch (Exception ex)` in your code. It just introduces bugs. You should only ever catch exceptions that you can recover from and that are exceptional. Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: In order to get a race condition here, you either have to call OperationAsync on the same instance several times (which you don't according to your statements), or have _proxy as a static member (you did not show the definition of that field). So I guess that the race condition has actually different cause in code which you did not show (i.e. you do call OperationAsync more than once on an individual instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you original code was calling `tsk.Wait();` you were blocking the calling thread while you run your proxy code on a background thread. There's no benefit and likely increased overhead doing it like this.

So, here's how to prevent the race condition:

```
public void OperationAsync(Action<BaseResult> callback)
{
    try
    {
        var r = new BaseResult();
        using (var proxy = new WebServiceClient<T>(_fullURL))
        {
            try
            {
                r.Value = proxy.Channel.ExecuteOperation(SecurityToken());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                r.Error = ex;
            }
        }
        if (callback != null)
        {
            callback(r);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        FileManager.Log(ex);
    }
}
```